# Is there a QGIS mailing list that only announces new releases?

Tags: qgis

Is there a mailing list for QGIS that announces only new releases / new binary packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no specific mailing list just for releases.

This news is sent via the normal user mailing list.

Comment: ... then can we make one? It would be very useful (for me; presumably others). Looking at the list archives, I would guess less than 2% of the posts on the user list relate to 'there is new software available for download'. Not a good signal/noise ratio for this purpose. Do you know who I should contact?

Comment: Well, I can't decide on that. Please ask at the existing mailing list.